# QStyleItemDelegate checkbox doesn't match stylesheet

Tags: python, pyside2

I've made a custom StyleItemDelegate and for some reason when it paints the checkbox indicator, it doesn't match what is defined in my Stylesheet. How can I fix this? You can see on the right side of the application that the StyleSheet properly affects how the checkbox is displayed in the default listview paint event.

**Update #1**

I've made a custom style item delegate to support rich text html rendering which all works great. I need to re-implement the checkbox since i've overwritten the paint event and ensure the checkbox is still available. However my text is overlapping the checkbox making it un useable. As a result when trying to paint the checkbox indicator, the highlighting of the ListItem is broken and only shows a slim blue strip on the left side.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
################################################################################
# imports
################################################################################
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


################################################################################
# QStyledItemDelegate
################################################################################
class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    MARGINS = 10


    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent, *args)


    # overrides
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        '''
        Description:
            Since labels are stacked we will take whichever is the widest
        '''
        options = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(options, index)

        # draw rich text
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))
        doc.setDocumentMargin(self.MARGINS)
        doc.setDefaultFont(options.font)
        doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
        return QtCore.QSize(doc.idealWidth(), doc.size().height())


    # methods
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        painter.setClipping(True)
        painter.setClipRect(option.rect)

        opts = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(opts, index)

        style = QtGui.QApplication.style() if opts.widget is None else opts.widget.style()
        
        # Draw background
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight().color())
        else:
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush))

        # Draw checkbox
        if (index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable):
            cbStyleOption = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()

            if index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole):
                cbStyleOption.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            else:
                cbStyleOption.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off

            cbStyleOption.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled
            cbStyleOption.rect = option.rect.translated(self.MARGINS, 0)
            style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_CheckBox, cbStyleOption, painter, option.widget)

        # Draw Title
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole))
        doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
        doc.setDocumentMargin(self.MARGINS)
        doc.setDefaultFont(opts.font)

        ctx = QtGui.QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext()

        # highlight text
        if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            ctx.palette.setColor(option.palette.Text, option.palette.color(option.palette.Active, option.palette.HighlightedText))
        else:
            ctx.palette.setColor(option.palette.Text, option.palette.color(option.palette.Active, option.palette.Text))

        textRect = style.subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, option)
        painter.translate(textRect.topLeft())
        painter.setClipRect(textRect.translated(-textRect.topLeft()))
        doc.documentLayout().draw(painter, ctx)
        
        # end
        painter.restore()


################################################################################
# Widgets
################################################################################
class ListViewExample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    '''
    Description:
        Extension of listview which supports searching
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListViewExample, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QListView {
                color: rgb(255,255,255);
                background-color: rgb(60,60,60);
            }
            QCheckBox, QCheckBox:disabled { 
                background: transparent; 
            }
            QWidget::indicator {
                width: 12px;
                height: 12px;
                border: 2px solid rgb(90,90,90);
                border-radius: 3px;
                background: rgb(30,30,30);
            }
            QWidget::indicator:checked {
                border: 2px solid rgb(76,175,80);
                background: rgb(0,255,40);
            }
        ''')

        self.itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Sample')

        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listView.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128,128))
        self.listView.setModel(self.itemModel)
        self.listView.setVerticalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)

        self.checkboxA = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Sample')

        self.listViewA = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.listViewA.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128,128))
        self.listViewA.setModel(self.itemModel)
        self.listViewA.setVerticalScrollMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkbox,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listView,1,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkboxA,0,1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listViewA,1,1)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


################################################################################
# Widgets
################################################################################
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ListViewExample()
    window.resize(600,400)
    window.listView.setItemDelegate(MyDelegate())
    window.itemModel.clear()
    
    for i in range(10):
        html = '''
        <span style="font-size:12px;">
          <b> Player <span>&#8226;</span> #{}</b>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size:11px;">
          <b>Status:</b> <span style='color:rgb(255,0,0);'>&#11044;</span> Active
            <br>
          <b>Position:</b> WR
            <br>
          <b>Team:</b> <span style='color:rgb(0,128,255);'>&#9608;</span> Wings
        </span>
        '''.format(i)
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        item.setData(html, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        item.setCheckable(True)
        window.itemModel.appendRow(item)

    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QStyle painting functions assume that you're using the default behavior of that style for the control/primitive. This means that, in most cases, the last `widget` argument can be ignored, since no overriding is being considered.

When using stylesheets, instead, things change. If the widget or *any* of its parents (including the QApplication) has a style sheet, the widget will use an internal QStyleSheetStyle, inheriting the behavior of the QApplication style, and overridden by any style sheet set for the parents.
In this case, that argument becomes mandatory, as the underlying QStyleSheetStyle will need to check if the widget has (or inherits) a stylesheet and eventually "climb" the widget tree in order to know *if* and *how* any custom styling has been set for it.

You just need to add that to the arguments of the function:

```
    style.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_CheckBox, cbStyleOption, painter, 
                      option.widget)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The above solves the issue of the styling, but not of the drawing.

While the appearance of a check box in an item view is usually the same of a QCheckBox (and the `::indicator` pseudo selector can be used for both), they are actually painted with different functions by the style.

The problem of your implementation is that you're drawing with `drawControl` and `CE_CheckBox`, but for item views you must use `drawPrimitive` and `PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck`. Also, since you're just translating the original option rect, the result is that `drawControl` will paint over a rectangle that is big as the *whole* item rectangle (thus painting over the selection).

The proper solution is to create a *new* QStyleOptionViewItem based on the existing one, and use the rectangle returned by `subElementRect` with `SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator`.

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if (index.flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable):
            cbStyleOption = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(opts)

            if index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole):
                cbStyleOption.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_On
            else:
                cbStyleOption.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Off
            cbStyleOption.state |= QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled

            cbStyleOption.rect = style.subElementRect(
                style.SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator, opts, opts.widget)

            style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck, 
                cbStyleOption, painter, opts.widget)
```

Note that you should not use translation in the painting, as that would make it inconsistent with the mouse interaction.

To translate the element, use the `top` and `left` properties in the stylesheet instead:

```
            QWidget::indicator {
                left: 10px;
                ...
            }
```

Also note that you're getting the text rectangle using the original option, which is not initialized, so that could return an invalid rectangle; you should then use the actually initialized option and also use the widget argument as explained above:

```
    textRect = style.subElementRect(QtWidgets.QStyle.SE_ItemViewItemText, 
        opts, opts.widget)
```

Comment: I added that but now my row selection is completely out of whack i updated the original post to show the issue. How do i resolve that?

Comment: Also noticed the checkbox no longer works, so i have to update the user interaction somewhere since im repainting the checkbox? Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @JokerMartini just to clarify, what are you *exactly* trying to achieve with the custom painting? Because after studying your code it's not really clear to me. The problem of the selection background is that you're just translating the rectangle of the option and drawing a full QCheckBox control (which overrides the default background with that set for QWidget in the QSS), but that rectangle includes the *whole* item area, while you should use `style.subControlRect` to get the rectangle of `SE_ItemViewItemCheckIndicator`, and then use `drawPrimitive` with `PE_IndicatorItemViewItemCheck`.

Comment: The problem of the click rectangle already exists for your previous implementation (if you didn't notice before it's probably because the default indicator is bigger), and that's because you're just translating the drawing, but the delegate doesn't know that when checking for mouse events, so it uses the default positioning. To translate the control, use `QAbstractItemView::indicator { margin-left: 10px; }`. I also strongly discourage you to use generic `QWidget` styling, because it often creates problems with complex widgets, most usually with the scroll bars of any scroll area; that happens

Comment: because with such widgets when you style *anything*, you need to style *everything*. That's explained in the [Sub-Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls) section of the QSS syntax: "With complex widgets such as QComboBox and QScrollBar, if one property or sub-control is customized, **all** the other properties or sub-controls must be customized as well.". If you only want to override the default foreground and background color, change the palette of the top level parent, by setting the `Window` and `WindowText`, and eventually `Base`, `AlternateBase` and `Text`.

Comment: I can update the original post to show the entire problem. I was trying to isolate the issue to just the checkbox. I'll post it tomorrow and comment here when I do to show the issue.

Comment: @musicanmante i updated the original post to showcase the end goal and the true issue im experiencing. Can you please help me out with that.

Comment: @JokerMartini see the update, it should fix both the click and selection issues.